# Cargar varios CSV en dataframe en phyton?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

tengo un conjunto de archivos csv cada uno con un millon de datos, estoy intentando cargarlos en un solo dataframe hasta ahora trate de cargarlos en una lista con exito pero necesito que este en un solo dataframe para analizar esos datos.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Primero especificamos un patrón del archivo 
# y lo pasamos como parámetro en la función glob

csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')

# Mostrar el archivo csv_files, el cual es una lista de nombres

print(csv_files)


list_data = []
  
# Escribimos un loop que irá a través de cada uno de los nombres de
# archivo a través de globbing y el resultado final será la lista dataframes

for filename in csv_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    list_data.append(data)

# Para chequear que todo está bien, mostramos la list_data por consola

list_data   
pd.concat(list_data,ignore_index=True)
```

Su ayuda por favor

---

Solo lo añade a una lista de dataframe y yo lo necesito en un solo dataframe, lo hice con dos ejemplos manualmente pero necesito un bucle for para q se convatenen ya que tengo varios archivos csv

Comment: Pregunta: `pd.concat(list_data,ignore_index=True)` no estaría haciendo justamente lo que esta preguntando?

Comment: Y de paso.. Bienvenido Diego Quezada a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo entendí lo que pasa es que no lo tenia asignado a una variable

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono correctamente